# How did Bryan find his ex-wife in Taken 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, taken-2

How did Bryan find the ambush his ex-wife was taken to? He remembered all the things to find the first place he and his wife were taken and suddenly he found his wife. How is that possible?

Answer (score 6):

When *he* is kidnapped (and is busy memorising the route being taken), the Albanians first stop off at the local HQ and then take him to the second location where his wife is tortured. When his wife is moved after his escape, he guesses that the baddies would have taken her to their HQ. He is therefore able to retrace the route to it and rescue his wife.